# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'timeout'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-df22a7fa1657> in <module>
     43 '''
     44 
---> 45  resp = urllib.request.urlopen(Imagen, timeout=300)
     46  background = Image.open(resp).convert("RGBA")
     47  background.thumbnail((150,150))

1 frames
/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    513                 req.data = data
    514 
--> 515         req.timeout = timeout
    516         protocol = req.type
    517 

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'timeout
```

Im run this code on Colab of google

and I have this problem with

```
 resp = urllib.request.urlopen(Imagen, timeout=300)
```

When Imagen is a list of URLS, in a csv file.

Comment: You can't pass a list of names.  `urlopen` expects a single string.  You'll need to do this in a loop, `for name in Imagen:`.  Further, the message suggests that `Imagen` is actually a floating point number.  Show us more of the code.

Comment: Somehow it's calling something like this:
```import urllib.request
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(1.0, timeout=300)```

Answer (score 0):

The function `urllib.request.open()` accepts either a single string `url` as it's first arg or a [Request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request) object, not a list of urls.  If you dig into it, you can see that the [open function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/urllib/request.py#L496) assumes that the arg is a `Request` object unless it is a string. You're running into a situation where you're passing it a `float` (not sure how this is happening if you're passing it a list of strings) and the `open` function expects a Request object, and thus returns an error.  To fix I would suggest examining the `Imagen` object more closely and then either creating `Request` objects from the `url`s in the `csv` or simply sending the individual `url`s themselves to `urllib.request.open` in a loop.